# HiddenField.value is undefined in JS

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

In my aspx markup I have the following defined:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="hidField" />
```

I have C# code as follows, which gives my hidden field a value:

```
hidField.value = check().ToString();
```

assume that check is a function which returns true, for simplicity.

I made JS code to do the following:

```
_myBool = $("#hidField");
alert(_myBool.value);
```

This alerts undefined.

For debugging purposes, I stepped through and saw that in C#, hidField.value is indeed true.
And I tried alerting _myBool.length which returned 1 and _myBool which returned [Object object] so Im not calling undefined on undefined.

Comment: Did you miss the `$`? `$("#hidField")` also, you should either use `.val()`, or `[0].value` not `.value`

Comment: I had the dollar sign, but yes you're right. it should've been .val() I guess I did .val earlier but I forgot the parantheses

Comment: Make sure you select one of the below answers as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
_myBool = $("#hidField");  //my bool is a jQuery Object
alert(_myBool.val());   //can only get value with .val()
```

OR

```
_myBool = $("#hidField")[0];  //[0] gets the element in the object
alert(_myBool.value);  //can use the javascript .value
```

Answer (score 2):

Missing **$** symbol..

```
var  _myBool = $("#hidField");

alert(_myBool[0].value); // DOM Object 

alert(_myBool.val() );  // jQuery Object
```

Also note the selector might Not work with `runat="server"` attribute as it prepends the content placeholder..

This is a better selector

```
 var _myBool = $('[id*="hidField"]');
```

Comment: It should work with my selector since I made ClientIDMode to be Static

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the dollarsign and also use the val() function

```
alert($("#hidField").val());
```

Comment: I think you know what you did wrong, but here you go : http://api.jquery.com/val/ 
Value is for dom elements and val() is use on jQuery selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the right ID:

```
_myBool = $("#<%= hidField.ClientID %>").val();
```

View your source when the page loads and check for that field. Chances are the ID is not "hidField". The code above will be correct.